# Local domain simulation with Apache2 and Yii

Tags: apache2, dns, localhost, yii

I'm trying to convert `http://localhost/website` to `http://website.loc`, but I'm not able to do that. Here's what I could do:

I edited /etc/hosts (I'm on Ubuntu) by changing `127.0.0.1 localhost` to `127.0.0.1 localhost website.loc` and saved changes

I created a new file named `website` inside `/etc/apache2/sites-available` with this content:

```
<virtualhost website.loc>
        ServerName website.loc
        DocumentRoot /home/myuser/projects/website/
        <directory /home/myuser/projects/website/>
                AllowOverride all
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </directory>
</virtualhost>
```

And I created a softlink to sites-enabled to enable this. After that, I restarted Apache.
By the way, I am using the Yii framework with any request to / redirected to /index.php, so index.php is not needed in the query.

So, when I write website.loc/ into chrome, it moves me to http://website.loc/site/login (the login index page, that's almost expected even if I was logged in as localhost, because the site url "changed" to website.loc, so the cookies are not shared), but the content is:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /website/index.php was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu) Server at website.loc Port 80
```

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks in advance, mates

**Edit:** It was all about the .htaccess inside /home/myuser/projects/website. It's RewriteBase was pointing to /website. Changing this to / and it worked like charm. Thanks @Chux for reminding me to check the .htaccess!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, http://website.loc/index.php, check if that work. If that work, means that you need to create an .htaccess in your website root folder to enable that route format

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It redirects me to website.loc/site/login, just like if I wrote website.loc. I already did an .htaccess to do all the redirection stuff, and that reminded me that I had a RewriteBase inside pointing to /website. Well, thanks!